# I have an Intel i217 -v Ethernet Controller and nothing is working for internet connection

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, ethernet

I built a server yesterday with a Gigabyte g1 sniper. It uses the Intel i217 -v for ethernet. I installed the drivers and everything and nothing is working to get ethernet working. I attached the output of `dmesg | grep e1000e` Any Ideas???? Thank you
I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

The screenshot of server output

[image]

Comment: Trust it is named with some other. In the first place whether eth0 is in your interface by ifconfig -a . On the off chance that it is not accessible may be it will exhibit for the sake of p1p1. In the event that you need it to be eth0 add biosdevname=0 to the boot choice in /etc/default/grub.

Answer (score 0):

1)First check whether ip address is able to generate from the network connection through cable by using,

ifconfig -a

2)Check whether auto assigning of ip is working by using,

sudo dhclient eth0

3) If the process stop in middle, reboot by using,

sudo dhclient eth0

After rebooting  edit the file and set the static ip by using the following command,

"/etc/network/interfaces"

From:

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet dhcp

To:

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.0.150

netmask 255.255.255.0

gateway 192.168.0.1

network 192.168.0.0

broadcast 192.168.0.255

dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

4) Finally, restart your Ethernet by using,

$ service networking restart

$ ifdown eth1

$ ifup eth1

Comment: sudo dhclient eth0 Cannot find device eth0